# Getting the missing dates from a sql table

Tags: mysql, date, datediff

I have a mysql table with the rows: ID, name, startDate, endDate.

As a rule, the dates should be consecutive and i want to alert the user if an interval is missing.

Saying i have this dates inserted:

```
2012-03-25 -> 2012-03-29
2012-04-02 -> 2012-04-05
```

I wanna show a message like

```
"No dates found from 2012-03-29 to 2012-04-02. Please insert data for this interval"
```

Can this be done without surfing with php the entire table entries?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to be more thorough in your explanation. For example, if you have - 2012-01-03 -> 2012-01-05 and 2012-01-06 ->2-12-01-09, would that need to be displayed? By that I mean the gap bewteen 2012-01-05 and 2012-01-06.

Comment: it should alert that one day is missing, endDate of one entry should be the first of other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.endDate AS gapStart, (SELECT MIN(t3.startDate) FROM `table` t3 WHERE t3.startDate > t1.endDate) AS gapEnd
FROM `table` t1
LEFT JOIN `table` t2
    ON t1.endDate = t2.startDate
WHERE t2.startDate IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done without surfing the whole table using PHP, instead you have to surf the whole table using mysql. A crude solution would be:

```
SELECT a.enddate AS start_of_gap, 
(SELECT MIN(c.startdate)
 FROM yourtable c
 WHERE c.startdate>a.enddate) AS end_of_gap
FROM yourtable a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM yourtable b
   WHERE b.startdate=a.enddate + INTERVAL 1 DAY
);
```

I expect if I thought about it some more, there will be a more efficient (but likely less obvious) method.

Comment: can you please be more specific? i got two rows, startDate and endDate but you used a row named date everywhere. thanks

Comment: Whoops - some confusion here. hadn't read the question properly and assumed the data was normalised. I'll will amend the query - BTW those are columns or attributes - not rows.

Answer (score 0):

This works. I include code for creating table and inserting data for testing purposes.

```
 create table dates(
id int(11) not null auto_increment,
name varchar(16) not null,
startDate date,
endDate date,
primary key(id)
);

insert into dates (name,startDate,endDate) 
values('personA', '2012-03-25', '2012-03-29'),
      ('PersonB','2012-04-02', '2012-04-05');
```

So here is the query:

```
 select d1.endDate,d2.startDate 
 from dates d1, dates d2 
 where (d1.id+1) =d2.id and d1.endDate < d2.startDate;
```

Comment: You cannot assume that both the IDs and date ranges are sequential especially when you consider that rectifying the situation will require an insert with values covering the gap. The newly inserted row will not be in sequence.

Comment: focusing on avoiding subquery, I missed that detail. I up-vote your comment. Thanks for sharing your observation.